# VHDL using an output from an instantiated entity in my toplevel entity

Tags: vhdl

I've a VHDL code with a top entity and several other entities. Now there is an output in one of the subentities of which the value has to be brought to the toplevel entity to show it in my simulation program.
How can i do that?

TOP entity:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity multiplier is
    port( Clk   : in        std_logic; -- Clock
          A,B   : in        std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- A and B
          Start : in        std_logic; -- Start
          Y     : buffer    std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); -- Result of A * B
          Ready : out       std_logic); -- Ready
end multiplier;

architecture structural of multiplier is

-- declaration of signals between different sub-circuits inside the multiplier
signal smInit, smCheck, smAdd, smShift, smZero, smReady, Stop : std_logic;
signal SR_A, SR_B, ADDout, MUXout : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

begin
io01: Ready <= smReady;

-- Instantiation of the FSM controller
sm01: entity work.FSM port map( Start, Stop, SR_A(0), Clk,
smReady, smInit, smCheck, smAdd, smShift, smZero);

-- Instantiation of the other sub-circuits and their connections
    SR1: entity work.Shifter port map(smInit, smShift, '0', Clk, A, SR_A);
    SR2: entity work.Shifter port map(smInit, smShift, '1', Clk, B, SR_B);
    A1: entity work.Add16 port map(SR_B, Y, ADDout);
    M1: entity work.Mux16 port map(smAdd, ADDout, Y, MUXout);
    G1: entity work.Reg16 port map(smInit, Clk, MUXout, Y);
    Z1: entity work.AllZero port map(SR_A(7 downto 0), Stop);
end structural; -- end of the multiplier architecture`
```

Now in the following subentity there is output S which i need to be able to call in the toplevel entity:

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Add16 is
port( A, B : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
S : buffer std_logic_vector(15 downto 0));
end Add16;
architecture behavior of Add16 is
signal Addout : out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
begin
S <= A + B;
end behavior;
```

How do i do that?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 3. Design entities and configurations "A design entity represents a portion of a hardware design...". `A1` is an instantiation of entity `Add16`where formal port `S` has a positional association with actual signal `ADDout` in the port map aspect. 6.5.7 Association lists "An association list, ..., establishes correspondences between formal or local generic, port, or parameter names on the one hand and local or actual names, ... on the other." Evaluate the actual, component instantiation statements (11.7) are concurrent, simulation is event driven (14.7 Execution of a model).

Comment: I recommend not to use `buffer` ports. You already have defined a signal `Addout` which is unused, so use it internally and assign it to `S`, which will be an `out` port then. Besides, I don't quite understand your problem. You have a signal `ADDout` in your top-level, which ist connected to the `S` port of your `Add16` entity.

Comment: Well, the ADDout signal doesn't show in my modelsim(simulating program), my teacher tells me i have to link the signal to the toplevel entity. So im trying it with "signal", still doesnt show addout in modelsim

Comment: @sad In modelsim, add all signals to your wave window recursively using the modelsim command `add wave -r *`.

Comment: @juergen that didnt work because the signal is not connected to the top level entity. I need some one to explain to me how i can connect the output S of my sub entity to the top level entity. from there im able to add the wave

Answer (score 1):

VHDL-2008 has a "external names" concept, whereby a hierarchical reference is possible, so you don't need to manually route internal signals through the hierarchy if the test bench needs access to the value.

If the top-level test bench name is `tb` and the `multiplier` instance name is `multiplier_e` then an alias for the `S` port on `Add16` can be created in the test bench using:

```
alias S_tb is <<signal .tb.multiplier_e.A1.S : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)>>;
```